# RoR: Polymorphic Associations: ID and Type are nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I'm creating an app in Ruby on Rails where users can listen to 2 different types of songs. I want to track each song(and type) that a user listens to. User can listen to a user_song or a master_song.
My first thought was to use polymorphic associations.

Firstly, my user model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :song_listens, :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

and then. I declare polymorphic this way:

```
class SongListen < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :listenable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :user

class UserSong < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :song_listens, :as => :listenable, :class_name => "SongListen"

class MasterSong < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :song_listens, :as => :listenable, :class_name => "SongListen"
```

My SongListens migration:

```
class CreateSongListens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :song_listens do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.references :listenable, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The problem comes in when I try save a user's song listen in the polymorphic table. I get nil for type and id. See -->:

```
[["created_at", Mon, 07 May 2012 18:25:34 UTC +00:00], ["listenable_id", nil],["listenable_type", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 07 May 2012 18:25:34 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
```

As you can see, the user_id is being set.

My SongListensController:

```
def create
@song_listen = current_user.song_listens.build(params[:listenable_id => :user_song_id])
@song_listen.save
end

def create_ms_listen
@song_listen = current_user.song_listens.build(params[:listenable_id => :master_song_id])
@song_listen.save
end
```

My view:

```
<% @user_songs.each do |user_song| %>
<td><%= link_to 'Play Song', user_song.song.url, class: :play, remote: :true %></td>
<% end %>

<% @master_songs.each do |master_song| %>
<td><%= link_to 'Play Song', master_song.m_song.url, class: :play, remote: :true %></td>
<% end %>
```

I think this explains the majority of my problem, but for fun, I'm using ajax to create song listen through a music player which sends data through route to SongListen create action:

```
$('a.play').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1")
        .jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: this.href })
        .jPlayer("play");
$.ajax({
  url: '/create_ms_listen.json',
  data: { "master_song_id" : "master_song.id"},
  async: false
  });
$.ajax({
  url: '/create_us_listen.json',
  data: { "user_song_id" : "user_song.id"},
  async: false
  });
  .....
```

Which goes to my routes:

```
match "create_us_listen.json" => "song_listens#create"

match "create_ms_listen.json" => "song_listens#create_ms_listen"
```

I know my goal is to somehow set the listenable type and id in the SongListen table but so far they have both been nil. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
params[:listenable_id => :user_song_id]
```

Can you see why?

Try that:

```
def create
    @song_listen = current_user.song_listens.build(params[:song_listen]) do |sl|
        sl.listenable_id = params[:song_id]
    end
    @song_listen.save
end
```

Not sure how you get the song_id, but that's the idea.

---

```
$("#jpId").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {
    // This event is fired when a song start playing,
    // so do your ajax request here.
    // Not sure how to get the id of your song.
    // You can access your media with event.jPlayer.status.media,
    // and from there, get the name or id of your song I guess
});
```

Comment: Hi. @robin I'm now setting the listenable_id but its 0 :(. I edited to add my view action and route. to the question.

Comment: Ok, so it would be `params[:master_song_id]` instead of `params[:song_id]`. But in your javascript, you dont actually send the id: `data: { "master_song_id" : "master_song.id"}`. "master_song.id" being just a string, it wont work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried making it "<%= master_song.id %>" too but it didn't work. Because a song_listen is dependent on a song playing through the music player, I figured I'd have to go through the jquery song play click function to pass the id to controller. Would you suggest another way of doing this or am I hitting a dead end?

Comment: Is there an event fired by the plugin when you play a song? If yes, you could use that. Basically your goal is now to get the id of the song playing, whether it is by using an attribute in the dom or getting it via the plugin.

Comment: So, the event is taking the absolute path of the song. I figured it might be possible to convert with to_integer 'to_i' but didn't work either